# vb.net String to Date only

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

Good day, I have a string 2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM
so, I've tried this

Dim sampleOnly As String = "2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM"

```
If sampleOnly <> Nothing Then
 Dim bdate As Date

 bdate = CDate(sampleOnly)
```

but there's an error.

> string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

I've tried this one too.

Dim bdate = DateTime.ParseExact(sampleOnly, "yyyy-MM-dd", Nothing)

Dim bdate As Date = Date.ParsesampleOnly

Dim bdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(sampleOnly)

But I still have an error. Please Help. thanks

**NOTE**: I want my output to be date only.

Comment: 2/2/2020 is either MM-dd-yyyy or dd-MM-yyyy, why would you expect it to be parsed with yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: I've tried also MM-dd-yyyy or dd-MM-yyyy. it didn't work

Comment: thats because none have the AM/PM designator in them - TryParseExact means EXACT

Comment: Also since you have the time componen there, your format string must also include the [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifier

Comment: The code in your question runs without error in my computer. In other words `Dim bdate As Date = CDate("2/2/2020 12:00:00 AM") does **not** throw and exception.

Comment: @Blackwood  That's the weird part. I know that it will run. But not this time

Comment: I ran it with that the exact time in your question. What is the culture setting you are using (US? UK? something else?)

Comment: Or as @Plutonix points out, you can use `TryParseExact`, but you must specify the proper [Custom DataTime Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (including the AM/PM indicator).

Comment: by the way, I want date only. if you have an answer please provide it. For me to check it or mark it as answer

Comment: @ thank you for the help guys, I miss a lot of things. it's ok now.

Answer (score 1):

You must parse the whole string first and then truncate the time.  The EXACT format specifier would be "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt" or "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", depending on your culture.  `DateTime.ParseExact` will give you a `DateTime` containing the full date and time.  You can then get the `Date` property value of that to get another `DateTime` with the time truncated.